# c++ nested initialization of template queue class

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array, nested, queue

Hey I have created this templated Queue class that works for all types except for nesting within itself for some reason.

Here is the queue class:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

//Queue node class.
template <class T>
class QueueNode
{
    public:
        T m_Data;
        QueueNode *m_NextNode;
        QueueNode(const T data_, QueueNode *nextValue_ = NULL)
        {
            m_Data = data_;
            m_NextNode = nextValue_;
        }
        QueueNode(QueueNode *nextValue_ = NULL)
        {
            m_NextNode = nextValue_;
        }
};

//Queue class.
template <class T>
class Queue
{
    public:
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // CONSTRUCTORS AND DESTRUCTORS
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Queue();
        ~Queue();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Error Codes
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        enum ERC_QUEUE
        {
            ERC_NO_ERROR,
            ERC_QUEUE_EMPTY
        };

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // METHODS
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Check if queue is empty.
        bool IsEmpty();

        //Check if queue is empty.
        int GetQueueSize();

        //Clear the queue.
        void Clear();

        //Dequeue X nodes and delete them.
        //If there the requested number of nodes to delete exceeds the number of nodes in the actual list,
        //the function will return an empty list.
        void Queue<T>::FlushNodes(unsigned short numNodes);

        //Add an item to the end of the queue.
        void Enqueue(T data_);

        //Get an item from the front of the queue.
        ERC_QUEUE Dequeue(T &data_);

        //Get an item from the front of the queue without removing it.
        ERC_QUEUE Peek(T &data_);

    private:
        QueueNode<T> *m_Head;
        QueueNode<T> *m_Tail;
        int m_Size;
};


//Template implementation

template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
    : m_Size(0)
{
    //Create empty queue with front and rear pointing to NULL.
    m_Head = m_Tail = NULL;
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue()
{
    Clear();
}

template <class T>
bool Queue<T>::IsEmpty()
{
    //If front is NULL then the queue is empty.
    return m_Head == NULL;
}

template <class T>
int Queue<T>::GetQueueSize()
{
    return m_Size;
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::Clear()
{
    QueueNode<T> *tmp;

    //Go through each node until the end of the queue.
    while (m_Head != NULL)
    {
        //Point tmp to next node.
        tmp = m_Head->m_NextNode;

        //Delete current node.
        delete m_Head;

        //Point front to next node.
        m_Head = tmp;
    }

    m_Size = 0;
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::FlushNodes(unsigned short numNodes)
{
    QueueNode<T> *tmp;

    //Go through each node until the end of the queue or the number of requested
    //nodes to be removed have been removed.
    while (m_Head != NULL && numNodes != 0)
    {
        numNodes--;
        m_Size--;

        //Point tmp to next node.
        tmp = m_Head->m_NextNode;

        //Delete current node.
        delete m_Head;

        //Point front to next node.
        m_Head = tmp;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::Enqueue(T data_)
{
    //Create new node.
    QueueNode<T> *node = new QueueNode<T>(data_);
    m_Size++;

    //If queue is empty then point both front and rear to the new node.
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        m_Head = m_Tail = node;
        return;
    }

    //Add node to the end of the queue and repoint rear to the new node.
    m_Tail->m_NextNode = node;
    m_Tail = node;
}

template <class T>
typename Queue<T>::ERC_QUEUE Queue<T>::Dequeue(T &data_)
{
    //If queue is empty return NULL.
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        return Queue<T>::ERC_QUEUE_EMPTY;
    }

    //Save value from top node.
    data_ = m_Head->m_Data;

    //Point tmp to front.
    QueueNode<T> *tmp = m_Head;

    //Repoint front to the second node in the queue.
    m_Head = m_Head->m_NextNode;

    //Remove first node.
    delete tmp;

    //Update queue size.
    m_Size--;

    return Queue<T>::ERC_NO_ERROR;
}

template <class T>
typename Queue<T>::ERC_QUEUE Queue<T>::Peek(T &data_)
{
    //If queue is empty return NULL.
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        return Queue<T>::ERC_QUEUE_EMPTY;
    }

    data_ = m_Head->m_Data;

    return Queue<T>::ERC_NO_ERROR;
}

#endif //QUEUE_H
```

Here is what I want to do:

```
Queue<int>          tst;
Queue<Queue<int>>   tst2;

tst.Enqueue(1);
tst.Enqueue(2);
tst.Enqueue(3);

tst2.Enqueue(tst);
```

Everything compiles, but the program crashes at run-time. what's the deal!?

Comment: Considering you have templates and classes, you should not tag C, only C++.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @user2654735 If this is a homework assignment, and your teacher didn't discuss to you how and when to create a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator (rule of 3), then you were cheated.  These *must* be implemented for your Queue class to accept a `Queue<int>` as a template argument.  So I can see why you may have been puzzled by why it doesn't work -- it is something that needs to be taught to newbies, since usually they do not discover this serious omission by debugging alone.

Comment: Look at Rule of 3/5/0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one glaring mistake is that you're using a type `T` that is not safely copyable.

You do this:

```
void Enqueue(T data_);
```

But if type `T` is a `Queue<int>`, what do you think happens to `data_`?  A copy is made, and your `Queue` template class doesn't have correct copy semantics.  It is missing a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.

The crash happens in the destructor of `tst2` since this is a `Queue<Queue<int>>`, and you've hosed the memory way before the destructor call with the call to `tst2.Enqueue(tst);`.  As soon as you called that, you're dead (or will be).

You have the same errors in multiple places, and that is you're copying objects that are not safely copyable.

Example:

```
//Save value from top node.
data_ = m_Head->m_Data;
```

If `data_` is a `Queue<int>`, then again, you're dead in the water since assigning  a `Queue<int>` to a `Queue<int>` is a no-go.

So the way to fix this is to have your `Queue` class implement the [Rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to ensure that the copies work.  You need to implement these functions:

```
Queue(const Queue& rhs);
Queue& operator=(const Queue& rhs);
```

Also, test with a case like this:

```
int main()
{
    Queue<int> q1;
    q1.Enqueue(10);
    Queue<int> q2;
    q2 = q1;
    Queue<int> q3 = q2;
}
```

A program like that should not crash, show signs of memory leakage, etc. when `main` exits.  If it does, then you haven't implemented the copying correctly.